# Using cmp to check for transferring files not working

Tags: bash

I have a script in place to check for transferring files before it runs but it runs even if I know for a fact that there are transferring files. It seems like the 'cmp' operation isn't working properly. I need to make sure that I'm not grabbing any files before they are finished transferring. Code below:

```
different=1
compare1=~/Desktop/$$-testing1.txt
compare2=~/Desktop/$$-testing2.txt
waittime=10s
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
PRO="/Volumes/pubfiles/ConversionRequests/Processed"
DATEI=$(date +-%m-%d-%Y)

cd $PRO/Processed$DATEI
echo Checking if files are in process in ${PWD}...
while [ $different -eq 1 ]; do
ls -la@ 1> $compare1
sleep $waittime
ls -la@ 1> $compare2

if cmp $compare1 $compare2 ; then
    echo Files have not changed in $waittime. Continuing...
    different=0
else
    echo Files are still being transferred. Waiting $waittime...
fi
done

rm $compare1
rm $compare2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
ls -la
```

to:

```
du -sk
```

It seems that the problem is that `ls -la` will only listing the directories present and not their respective sizes in bytes so the cmp files will always be identical. By using:

```
du -sk
```

You get the size of the directories and the while loop will continuing as it should.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will probably not work. To make sure that you're not reading a file which some other process is currently writing, get the process to write the file with a temporary name. When it's finished, have it rename the file.

Then you can simply ignore temporary file names.

If you use a home-written script to transfer files, replace that with a proper transfer tool like `rsync(1)`.

If you're using a commercial product, file a bug. If they refuse to fix it, then they probably don't know what they're doing - find a better product.